# How to use a function pointer in a overloaded operator

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matrix

I was trying achieve a Matlab way to acess matrixes elements. For example, if i have the following in MatLab:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4]

 A =

 1     2
 3     4

>> A(1,1) = 5
```

Will generate this output:

```
A =

 5     2
 3     4
```

Is this possible to achieve with the operator () in c++? Thanks in advance.

@edit

Sorry guys, i think the resolve would be achieved by a function pointer.

Ill try to be more plain. I have a class matrix, I want to change a respective value of the class using the operator(), passing the number respective to the row and to the column.

Comment: What does this have to do with function pointers?

Comment: Without overloading anything, you can simply do `A[1][1] = 5`. Or you could use one of many existing `Matrix` classes (or write your own) and define a `()` operator.

Comment: OP might still want an overloaded `operator()` to achieve the 1-based indexing like matlab.

Comment: Please read the C++ FAQ on matrix operators: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html

Comment: As C uses zero-based indexing, it would be `A[0][0]` of course. Please edit your question clarify precisely what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<size_t I, size_t J>
class M
{
    public:
    M(double e00, ...)
    {
        // use arg_list :)
    }
    double& operator () (int i, int j)
    {
        return m[i-1][j-1];
    }
    private:
    double m[I][J];
};

M<2,2> A(1,2,3,4);
A(1,1)=5.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your sujecstion, but I cant compile the code I get the following error: "lvalue required as left operand of assigment" @edit I resolved the problem, tha was right, thank you :)